Connect my WFS and WMS service in GeoServer through QGIS
I have made this connection in previous situations, but this time it doesn't seem to work.
I have a GeoServer and I have WMS and WFS services enabled in two sections referred to them that I have read in documentation: Work Space (1, where I have my layers) and Servicies (2, to enable them specifically).






The layer preview in GeoServer works correctly when I select "OpenLayers", but when I try to connect through QGIS the error is this: "failed to download capabilities: service not available".
For what it's worth, I have tests with these URLs:

http://....*:8080/geoserver/web/
http://....*:8080/geoserver/wms
http://....*:8080/geoserver/(scheme)/wms?
http://....*:8080/geoserver/(schema)/wfs?
http://....*:8080/geoserver/ows
http://....*:8080/geoserver/ows?acceptversions=2.0.0

What is it with this error that I am not seeing?

you need to point your QGIS to the get capabilities example WMS " h ttp://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities"

try out the url in your browser and look at what is returned

@Mapperz, it still show me the same error. Maybe the problem is in Geoserver configuration

@IanTurton in the browser both options (wms and wfs with their modified URL) seem to display their XML structure correctly

Then you need to see what error QGis is seeing, use the network debug plugin to see what is being requested and returned

Well it just warns me:
2024-04-18T10:04:32     WARNING    Petición de red http://.*..***:8080/geoserver/ows?version=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities expirada
2024-04-18T10:04:32     WARNING    Download of capabilities failed:
Operación cancelada

I think that the problem could be the URL. Beacuse when I configure my GEOSERVER in "workspace" I wrote a name for URI name space: www...ar/***.

I have taste it adding it in QGIS but same problem

@IanTurton, where can we find this "network debug plugin"? I use QGIS 3.22.16, but was unable to find it with the plugin manager

I have tested this wms connection through a leaflet code and it works, but with some small error because it disappears when I add basemaps like Carto. But at least it works, but the problem in Qgis still occurs. I don't know if this can be a clue.

Look in plugins-> Manage and Install plugins->QGIS Network Logger

A lot of the WMS traffic can be seen without installing anything. Function button F12 opens the debugging/delelopment tools, or they can be selected from View-Panels...
